# Intellij IDEA trace object id while debugging

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While debugging in IntelliI IDEA, we can see:

```
item = {Object} [224780497]
```

Is any way to trace/output [224780497] to console?

Comment: Do you mean the hashCode or the object Id as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322903/deciphering-variable-information-while-debugging-java?

Comment: Yes, I need to remember items this way.

Comment: The value you specified `224780497` is probably the hashCode and not the object id (which is typically 1-5 digits). So you just have to log the hashCode yourself to get it in the console.

Comment: How can I get this hashcode of the Object by myself?

Comment: Just call `int myHashCode = someObject.hashCode();`