# What is the number in front of each obj in Evaluate Expression Window in intellijIdea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

when i use evaluate expression (ShortKey:Alt+F8) in IntelliJ i get a number in front of each obj is it some sort of unique id for each obj and is it universal for whole context of program (i mean, is it totally unique?)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these aren't just elements of an array?

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322903/deciphering-variable-information-while-debugging-java)