# How to set breakpoint condition to specific object instance in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Suppose I saw in debugger that `this` value for some instance is

```
{MyClass@6164}
```

Now, how to set a breakpoint in some method and set its condition so that is stops only if `this` is the same?

Comment: The number you're seeing is the [objectId reported to the debugger by the JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322903/deciphering-variable-information-while-debugging-java), and I'm not sure you can access it. Your best bet is probably by using the object's hash-code as already suggested. Even if multiple objects can have the same hash-code (normally) I wouldn't expect them to be that many, and when there are a few, you can visually filter them after that particular objectId

Answer (score 10):

[You can use a conditional breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-breakpoints.html).

Put a condition where you evalute `this.hashCode() == HASHCODE`. You can get the `HASHCODE` using the [Evaluate Expression](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/evaluating-expressions.html) feature.

Hope that helps.

[image: Conditional BreakPoint]