# Objects in Intellij IDEA's debugger

Tags: intellij-idea

While debugging in Intellij IDEA, I can see objects with **{TYPE@SOME_NUMBER}**, e.g. as can be seen in the picture below **{PersistentBag@8507}**.

What is **SOME_NUMBER**, e.g. **8507**?
How does Intellij calculates it?

[image: Intellij IDEA debugger]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322903/deciphering-variable-information-while-debugging-java

Answer (score 1):

That's basically just a memory reference. In general, you'll never need to do anything with it and can just ignore it.

I've never actually seen a scenario where you actually need to care about that number. Since Java manages memory for you, it won't really ever matter.

About the only thing I can think of that would matter would be you can use that number to determine if a value in two places is the same value, or just look the same.

For example, if you pass an object as a value to do different classes, they would both show the same `@SOME_NUMBER`, meaning they're the same object.